# Contact form for Angular.js application, scaffolded with yeoman angular full-stack

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am building an Angular.js application, scaffolded with yeoman, and I am looking for a way to integrate a regular contact form into that application, that sends a message to the recipient via email. Can anyone recommend such a contact form?

Comment: What actually are you looking for? A HTML boilerplate for that? What have you done so far?

Comment: I need a full contact form including validation - the latter can be done in HTML5, of course- and processing of the message through the contact form. It just needs to send an email with the information.  I am not sure about the right way to do this. I have found a couple of Angular.js scripts throught the net, but they all rely on php scripts that need to be processed as well. As I have an express server running client side in the application, I´m not sure on what would be the best way to process these php scripts in an angular application. I am looking for the simplies possible solution.